# Eigenvalues and eigen vectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to have a matrix for which eigen vectors won't change by changing the eigen values? Please help me! I am seraching for the answer to this question.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the  eigenvalues?

Comment: I mean the same eigen vector for all the eigenvalues...if such a matrix exists is there any particular form of that matrix?

Comment: Two different eigenvalues have different eigenvectors. More precisely $\ker(A-\lambda_1I)\cap \ker(A-\lambda_2I)=0$ for any eigenvalues $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: To be precise, the intersection is $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and not $\mathbf{0}$, i.e. it is the singleton the only element of which is the null vector.

Comment: @Frunobulax, sure. However in Linear Algebra, $0$ also denotes the trivial vector space, i.e. $\{0\}$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Really?  $\{\mathbf{0}\}=\mathbf{0}$?  Never saw that before.  Makes a set theorist shudder... :)

Comment: @Frunobulax: It's just a notation, doesn't mean a set. It makes sense when you consider the direct/tensor products $0\oplus M=M$ or $0\otimes M=0$.

Comment: @QuangHoang: OK, makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are not only different but also linear independent.

See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Famous_Theorems_of_Mathematics/Algebra/Linear_Transformations#Lemma_for_linear_independence_of_eigenvectors).

Comment: To look at it another way, given a matrix $A$ with eigenvector $u\neq 0$, the corresponding eigenvalue is uniquely determined by the definition:  $$ Au = \lambda u $$  Further, thus while two different eigenvectors $u,v$ might share a common eigenvalue, two different eigenvalues cannot share a common eigenvector.